# Node.js source code of require() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-modules

According to the document (https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html), `require()` function is one of the global objects/functions. But I'm having a hard time finding its source code on Github. Are they written in JS or C++? I was looking for them in https://github.com/nodejs/node project.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/05002373176e8758c8c604f06659e171de4ca902/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js#L19) seems to be it (in `node/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js`).

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, I think it's defined in [loader.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8828426af45adc29847d0d20717c8fa3eb9bb523/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L648-L655). And you can see it's implemented for all modules. 
It seems to be mapped to `global.require` in [node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap/node.js#L666)